# Windows 7 boot from USB

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot

I have working installation of OEM windows on 2.5" drive.
I did change my drive for SSD and install Ubuntu as main OS.

I have ICY BOX SATA<->USB3.0 box to connect original 2.5" drive to NB.

When I try to boot original Windows 7 via USB3.0, it doesn't work (error 0x000007b).

Is it possible to boot Windows 7 from USB3.0 ?

I do not want to reinstall windows (original OEM).
I can connect Windows drive to NB via SATA(to boot), so I can change any file on windows.

I did some research, and if I add USB drivers to Windows boot sequence it should work, but I don't have much experience with windows, so I have no idea how to do it.

NB is Lenovo ThinkPad L450

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if:

a) The machine you're using does not have BIOS that insists on handling boot order in a legacy way. You'll need either an up to date BIOS (exact details vary from machine to machine) or an EFI capable machine AND

b) Windows 7 installed on a GPT disk, not an MBR disk. GPT and MBR are different types of partition table. A GUID Partition Table disk allows partitions and disks to be more portable, whereas as Master Boot Record disk includes some interpartition relationship information in the partition map to provide legacy support. If your current windows install is on an MBR partition table disk then you will need to reformat and reinstall specifying GPT this time (sorry!).

You should get this option when formatting the disk using Windows 7 and above using Disk Management.

Note: MBR and GPT are partition table formats, not partition formats. Partition formats such as NTFS or FAT32 can exist on either an MBR or GPT partition table disk.